# Are there Window Manager developed using OCaml?

Tags: ocaml

Haskell has XMonad, CommonLisp has StampWM.  If there is one developed using OCaml, then it should be faster than those two.

Sincerely!

Comment: There is something called GwML, last updated in 2001, and its homepage is gone. What about xmonad and StumpWM is too slow for you, they seem really fast to me. Is it a "my language is better" thing?

Comment: It is not a "my language is better" thing.  I am an OCaml newbie and i want to know the real applcation developed using OCaml. In fact, i know of haskell through XMonad.

Comment: I doubt an ocaml WM would automatically be "faster than XMonad"; for such a GUI application, design has more importance than raw performance -- and it's even unclear OCaml would perform better on that use case. By the way, Swiestra has reimplemented a part of XMonad in Coq, so you could extract it to OCaml; but it's hard to get good performances from a naive extraction.

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure that a window manager is like the killer application for a functional language... I am far more impressed with programs like Coq or JaneStreets brokerage system.

Check out what JaneStreet Capital is doing with OCaml or what various research institutes are programming (e.g. INRIA). Of course you will only see what people are publishing...

Comment: Exactly. It doesn't prove anything to rewrite in language X programs that could already be written in C by one person in the 80s.

Answer (score 5):

GwML looks like it is available as part of [Efuns](https://github.com/korya/efuns) although it may no longer build.

The smallest WM source I can find is [TinyWM](http://freecode.com/projects/tinywm) with only 58 lines of (unobfuscated) C code, so the simplest way to get a fast OCaml WM might just be to rewrite that.

Answer (score 1):

A quick search gives me this [link](http://caml.inria.fr/cgi-bin/hump.en.cgi?sort=0&browse=111) about software written in OCaml which includes GwML. I don't know any **popular** Window Manager written in OCaml.